# How to use Hoeffding's Inequality to find a confidence Interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, probability-inequalities

I want an example that shows how to use Hoeffding's inequality to find a confidence interval for a binomial parameter *p* (probability of succes).

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we let $X_1, \ldots, X_n \stackrel{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim}$ Bernoulli$(p)$, then since $X_i \in [0, 1]$ for each $i$ Hoeffding's inequality says that
$$
P(|\bar{X} - p| \geq t) \leq 2 e^{- 2n t^2}
$$
or
$$
P(|\bar{X} - p| < t) \geq 1 - 2 e^{- 2n t^2} .
$$
If we want a $95\%$ confidence interval say, we can equate the right hand side to $0.95$ and solve for $t$ to get
$$
t = \sqrt{ - \frac{1}{2n} \log \left ( 0.025 \right )} .
$$
Rewriting the inequality above after plugging in this value of $t$ we have
$$
P \left (\bar{X} - \sqrt{ - \frac{1}{2n} \log \left ( 0.025 \right )} < p < \bar{X} + \sqrt{ - \frac{1}{2n} \log \left ( 0.025 \right )} \right ) \geq 0.95
$$
and so these values can be the endpoints of a $95\%$ confidence interval for $p$.